# changing aspect ratio values in code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Am using the height constraints to change imageview height when scrolling like this:

```
  UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations:{
        self.homeimage.image = UIImage(named: "smalllogo")
        self.homeimgheight.constant = 116
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
```

now i want to add aspect ratio to the imageview and do the same thing when scrolling ... just adding the aspect ratio .. the image will only change but the height will remain the same ..

how can i change the aspect ratio in code???

Comment: your current image is in aspect ratio.?

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen yes.. how to change it's value?

Comment: if the image is currently in aspect ratio according to the width and height. you need to change both width and height constraint i guess

Comment: image width is static..? and you want to set image heightconstraint according to the width of image ..?

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen no no ... the width is static and also the height .. but when scrolling a scroll view i want to change the height of the image and change the image itself

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen also i tried to change the width also but it didn't work...

Comment: you need to fill the entire imageview and it should be in aspect ratio. is that the case...?

Comment: @MuhammedAzharudheen just solved it .. check my answer if you are interested :) Thank you soo much!

Answer (score 0):

Just solved it like this:

```
self.homeimage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.homeimage.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1.0/3.23).isActive = true
```

hope this will help anyone in the future :)